# Bold / Cursive section of Tooltip text obtained from binding

Tags: silverlight, tooltip, text-styling

I have a tooltipservice set to an image, where I want to display a text.

Part of this text we wish to have in bold. Another part in cursive.

The text is obtained from the database and given to the tooltipservice via a binding (localization)

Example: "**this is bold** and *this is cursive* but this is normal style"

Is this possible?

I've found online that using the tags < Bold > and < /Bold > should work, but it doesn't seem to for me.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing i can think of is in your tooltip service style, add something like

```
   <TextBlock> 
    <Span FontWeight="Bold">Hello</Span> 
    <Span FontStyle="Italic">World</Span> 
  </TextBlock>
```

Not sure if this will work

Comment: it might work, but i'll have to split the text in multiple parts and I rather not do that.

Comment: That's true, the bold tags are not working for me either. Only other thing - if possible would be to put a rich text box inside the tool tip, i think then the text can be formatted how you want.